# Binding to a Namespaced Attribute in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

When bind to attributes(one-way) there are a couple of options you can either bind with `attr-name.bind="variable"` (also tried one-way and one-time) or using interpolation `attr-name="${variable}"`, either way though if you try to bind to a namespaced element such as xlink:href you currently get:

> Uncaught NamespaceError: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on
>   'Element': '' is an invalid namespace for attributes.

For have the following in a controller page.js:

```
export class page {
    constructor(){
        this.icon = 'blah';
    }
}
```

and the following in page.html:

```
<template>
  <svg class="icon ${icon}">
    <use xlink:href="${icon}"></use>
  </svg>
</template>
```

As I said either of the bind's above is throwing the given error.

Any thoughts on how to bind to this namespaced attribute?

Instrumented the bootstrap handleApp function to print the  full stack trace:

`Error: Failed to execute 'setAttributeNS' on 'Element': '' is an invalid namespace for attributes.
    at Error (native)
    at OoPropertyObserver.setValue (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/binding@0.3.3/system/property-observation.js:200:26)
    at InterpolationBinding.setValue (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.8.4/system/binding-language.js:214:35)
    at InterpolationBinding.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-binding@0.8.4/system/binding-language.js:202:22)
    at View.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.9/system/view.js:65:29)
    at ViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.9/system/view-factory.js:173:22)
    at BoundViewFactory.create (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.9/system/view-factory.js:128:39)
    at Repeat.processItems (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-resources@0.8.6/system/repeat.js:105:36)
    at Repeat.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating-resources@0.8.6/system/repeat.js:60:22)
    at BehaviorInstance.bind (http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/github/aurelia/templating@0.8.9/system/behavior-instance.js:67:39)`

Also if I hack the property-observation code to explicitly set the namespace it works, but this is really kludgy and likely to break quickly.

https://github.com/aurelia/binding/blob/master/src/property-observation.js#L153-L159 changed to:

```
setValue(newValue) {
    if (this.isSVG) {
      if(this.propertyName.indexOf('xlink:') >= 0){
        this.obj.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", this.propertyName, newValue);
      } else {
        this.obj.setAttributeNS(null, this.propertyName, newValue);
      }
    } else {
      this.obj[this.propertyName] = newValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling for namespaced elements in aurelia is now explicitly supported thanks to https://github.com/aurelia/binding/issues/34. No need to do anything special. This works for HTML and HTML5 issues with namespacing.